# Code for deciding ordinary floating point numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, floating-point, nan

I want to know a right and maybe elegant way in C++ to detect whether a floating point number is ordinary. By "ordinary floating point numbers", I mean those of double/float/long double type except NAN or INF.

Comment: @Drew That makes sense. My apologies.

Comment: In addition to the good answers, finite floating-point numbers are exactly those that make the condition `x - x == 0` true, for when you have good reasons to avoid including a header. Specialists will read it as an idiom but non-specialists will be annoyed, so use with care.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out [Boost.Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/fpclass.html). It defines all of these:

```
template <class T>
bool isfinite(T z); // Neither infinity nor NaN.

template <class T>
bool isinf(T t); // Infinity (+ or -).

template <class T>
bool isnan(T t); // NaN.

template <class T>
bool isnormal(T t); // isfinite and not denormalised.
```

Since C++11, these are in `<cmath>` too: [`std::isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan), [`std::isinf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isinf), [`std::isfinite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite), and [`std::isnormal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnormal).

Comment: Thank you. isfinite is what I have been looking for

Answer (score 3):

[`std::isfinite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isfinite) will return `true` for values that are **not** INF or NaN.

*(Edited to reflect a question edit)*